# Emulate Whitelisting of CIDR Range on Azure Sentinel

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

There is a way to use CIDR range in kusto? the code below only works if i remove the /24..

```
let whiteList = dynamic (["192.168.2.0/24", "192.168.1.0/24"]);  // setup a whitelist of range IP
OfficeActivity
| where Operation == "MailboxLogin" 
| where ClientIP in (whiteList)
| summarize count=count() by UserId
```

any solution please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
let WhiteList= @'^192\.168\.1|^192\.168\.2'; // put your internal networks
OfficeActivity
| where Operation == "MailboxLogin" 
| extend IswhiteList = iff(ClientIP matches regex WhiteList,"whiteList" ,"none" )
| where IswhiteList == "whiteList"
| summarize count=count() by UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at parse_ipv4()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parse-ipv4function

It looks like it should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

More IPv4 functions listed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalarfunctions#ip-v4-functions